# How do I estimate and plot model predicted marginal means from a GEE model fitted using the multgee package in R?

Tags: predictive-models, ordinal-data, generalized-estimating-equations, marginal-model

I am trying to obtain model-predicted means and CI's from a GEE model fitted with the ordLORgee function in the Multgee package in R. I was able to fit the model and estimate the predicted means over time for each level of the response variable. However I am not sure how to plot this, I have tried packages like emmeans but they don't support objects of class  “LORgee".

#category exchange local odds ratio structure

```
mod2 <- ordLORgee( formula = (bmi_class) ~ fage*TimeGroup + sex*TimeGroup + factor(smoking) + factor(smoking)*TimeGroup,
                     data = data_bmi,
                     id = id,
                     repeated = TimeGroup, 
                    LORstr = 'category.exch')
summary(mod2)

#Predicted values:
predicted = as.data.frame(mod2$fitted.values)
names(predicted) = c('1','2','3')
```

Comment: You might take a look at `emmeans::qdrg()` and see if you can get it to work. You'll have to give the data, model formula, coefficients, and vcov matrix. Then you can use the returned reference grid just like you'd use a model to obtain EMMs and plots.